# Remove Keyboard Input Field Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

At present I am getting this kind of keyboards for providing input in Android and iOS platforms.
Please see below image:
[image]

I mean Input Field remain attached with keyboard for preview purpose. I want to remove this.
For this purpose, I gone through this thread:
[Removing Android keyboard additional input field?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1408712/removing-android-keyboard-additional-input-field.html)

After this I have added following line of code:

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;
```

Still there is no change into output, please provide me some direction into this.

**EDIT: How to remove InputBox attached with Keyboard?**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Check my updated question...

Comment: Remove/Hide the InputField from the screen?

Comment: I hope you are seeing keyboard with big input box attached with it - that I want to disappear - whichever option is possible either hide or remove

Comment: Marked as duplicate. See the duplicate.

Comment: did you find the answer? hideinput = true not working

Comment: No, I think there is no way to solve this thing within Unity. We don't have the functionality of the input box as like core input box.